# Reliable FIFO messaging Java

Tags: java, rmi, messaging, fifo

I want to extend a small middleware system to add reliable FIFO communication and for that the connection between brokers need to be FIFO. Currently the communication layer of the middleware supports socket and RMI. However I do not think socket and RMI can provide FIFO ordering for the message objects.

Is there a way to enforce FIFO ordering on a message object level for RMI?

So far I have come to the conclusion to use something like JMS for the communication layer to guarantee FIFO ordering. Does this make sense? Or there are other lightweight alternatives?

I think another option would be using message numbers and implement this ordering by writing a small protocol on top of socket or RMI, but it seems like a lot of work and requires some expertise to handle special cases.

Comment: I am asking for possible ways of having reliable messaging in Java rather than a special product! My question is whether a messaging API like JMS can be used or there are other alternative methods/technologies, NOT PRODUCTS!

Comment: "However I do not think socket and RMI can provide FIFO ordering for the message objects." Why not?

Answer (score 2):

There are several open source messaging systems that are available, for example [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), and [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) - once you've got them set up they're all pretty easy to use.  If you're only communicating between threads and not processes then you can use a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) (most systems I've worked with use RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ/ZeroMQ/HornetQ to communicate between processes, and then disseminate messages between threads using a [Priority]BlockingQueue).

Comment: Thanks! I want to send messages between processes since each broker is on a different machine. So you think it would make sense to use a MoM as a communication layer for another MoM? And would this be the only way to achieve FIFO ordering?

Comment: @p00ya00 I think it makes sense to use MoM as a communication layer for another MoM in terms of simplicity - you're using a specialized piece of queueing software that's good at what it does instead of having to add queueing to the existing software with the potential of introducing bugs as a result, with the result that the hybrid system is more reliable.  (I have never had problems with the messaging system throwing up bugs - these have always come from the application layer.)  I am not aware of a way to do FIFO ordering with RMI.